# How to reference an array position with a variable name

Tags: c++, arrays, string, reference

What is the easiest way to reference an array location using a variable name?

```
string var = "foo";
string foo[] = { "My name is Bob", "My name is Tom" };
```

In this case, I want to print the second element of the array referenced by the variable var. I will have a few different arrays and the variable 'var' will keep getting changed to names of different arrays. I've tried:

```
cout << var[1] << endl;
```

But of course, that will only return the second character in the string since it's a group of characters. But I want to reference the name foo with the index of 1. 
How do I go about doing this?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're saying; but you could be looking for a map/dictionary.

Answer (score 3):

You can't; variable names aren't available at run-time.

If you want one variable to refer to another, use a reference or a pointer. For example,

```
string * var = foo;
cout << var[1] << endl;
```

Answer (score 3):

The only way I can think of is using a `std::map`.

```
std::map<std::string, std::vector<std::string>> mapOfArrays;
mapOfArrays["foo"] = { "My name is Bob", "My name is Tom" };
mapOfArrays["bar"] = { "My name is Jim", "My name is Sam" };

std::cout << mapOfArrays["foo"][1] << std::endl;
std::cout << mapOfArrays["bar"][1] << std::endl;
```

Comment: Not the "only" way , but defintely the Good way

Answer (score 1):

You also can try the following approach with using tuples. For example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>
#include <string>
#include <functional>

int main() 
{
    std::string bar = "foo";
    std::string foo[] = { "My name is Bob", "My name is Tom" };

    auto  var = std::make_tuple( std::ref( bar ), std::ref( foo ) );

    std::cout << std::get<0>( var )[0] << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::get<1>( var )[0] << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
f
My name is Bob
```

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that I understand the question, but perhaps structured binding declarations (C++17) could help:

```
void Bla()
{
    std::wstring _name[] = { L"Bo", L"Selecta" };

    auto [FirstName, LastName] = _name;

    std::wcout << FirstName << L" " << LastName << L"\n";
}
```

Works with tuples too.